# What is the state of IEEE 802.21 adoption?

Tags: wireless, standardisation

I am working on heterogeneous networking in wireless networks, and the IEEE Std 802.21 (Media Independent Handover) seems to tackle some of the problems I am facing. However, I could not find information on someone actually using it.

So my question is: What is the state of IEEE 802.21 adoption? It seems that the actual handover functionality for technologies like IEEE 802.11 is not part of the standard, so the benefits of using it instead of implementing a lightweight alternative may be small.

Is the standard already obsolete? Would it make sense to integrate it into a new prototype implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this standard has still not been adopted to any extent. Wikipedia explains:

> Crossing different administrative connectivity domains will require
> agreements among different network operators. Currently, such
> agreements are still not in place. In smart phones today, a user can
> manually select to use WiFi or cellular LTE, but the connections are
> not automatically maintained should a disconnection of one network
> occurs.
>
> Hence, seamless handovers across different wire/wireless networks are
> still not available today.